Direction of static friction in wheel
If a wheel is rolling right, that means the static friction on the stationary point that touch the ground is pointing left. That creates the torque that moves the wheel right.
But if that stationary point has velocity of $0$, and it wants to move to the left, there would be a static friction to the right. Then what is the correct direction?

"and it wants to move to the left" what do you mean wants to move to the left?

The friction between a wheel and surface depends not only on its velocity and angular velocity but also on the forces and torques acting on the wheel. Friction can point either forward or backward depending on the situation. Please clarify the exact setup you are talking about.

Your first sentence is already false. A wheel rolling to the right does not necessarily have friction to the left. Both directions, including zero, are possible. See my answer here.

You are thinking about velocity. You should be thinking about acceleration and force.
Suppose a spinning wheel sits on ice. Friction is $0$. The wheel can sit in one spot, or it can move over the ice. If it moves forward at the right speed, the bottom of the wheel has velocity $0$. The wheel is rolling. No friction is needed to keep it rolling.
Suppose a car rolls at constant speed down a road. Again, no friction is needed.
If the driver steps on the gas, the car exerts a torque on the wheels. They spin faster, and friction pushes them and the car forward. The car accelerates. In this case, friction is in the opposite direction of motion, as you said.
If the driver steps on the brake, the car exerts a torque on the wheels. They spin slower, and friction holds them and the car back. The acceleration of the car is backward. The car slows. In this case, friction is in the direction of the motion.
